# T4 generated code that needs access to a different namespace/project

Tags: c#, enums, t4

I am trying to use [Robert Koritnik's](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html) t4 template to generate Enums.

These arent regular enums, my company is using a `TypeSafeEnum` pattern that is used occasionally in java.  Its basically just a collection of classes with values.  This isnt important, except to note that the `TypeSafeEnum` base class is in a different project from my EDMX and template files.

I also cant reference the enum project in my DB project because it would create a circular reference.

So, when I generate the enum classes, I reference the base class but it doesnt exist.

My question then:

Is there a way to copy the T4 generated code over to the correct project?

Or perhaps a better way of generating the code so I could have access to both namespaces?

Here is a snippet of my generated code:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using xxxxxx.Core.Enums.BaseClasses;   //<--- Isnt referenced

namespace xxxxxx.Core.Enums
{
    /// <summary>
    /// InventoryAdjustmentType auto generated enumeration
    /// </summary>
    [GeneratedCode("TextTemplatingFileGenerator", "10")]
                                          //vvvvvvvv---- base class not referenced  
    public class InventoryAdjustmentType : TypeSafeEnum<InventoryAdjustmentType, byte>
    {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `.tt` file to the project where you want the generated files to be:

```
- Solution "MySolution"
   |-> Project "DBProject"
   |      |-> MyModel.edmx
   |
   |-> Project "EnumsProject"
          |-> References
          |      |-> DBProject.dll
          |
          |-> MyT4Template.tt
                 |-> Generatedfiles.cs
```

and then make sure you provide the proper path to the `EDMX` file inside the T4 template so that it can read it properly:

```
var edmxPath = "..\DBProject\MyModel.Edmx";
```